# Configuring pm2 for cluster mode with express and nginx?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, pm2

We are in the process of setting up an express based Node.JS app with pm2.

What we are confused about is whether each instance of a pm2 app needs to be running on its own port and then have a configuration nginx to deal with load balancing over each instance?

Also how would we tell pm2 to use a separate log file for each instance?

Our pm2 configuration:

```json
{
    "apps": [{
      "name": "myapp",
      "script": "dist/index.js",
      "args": ["server"],
      "watch": false,
      "merge_logs": true,
      "error_file": "/var/log/myapp/stderr-web.log",
      "out_file": "/var/log/myapp/stdout-web.log",
      "pid_file": "/var/run/myapp/myapp.pid",
      "instance_var": "NODE_INSTANCE_ID",
      "env": {
        "LOGGING_MAIN_FILENAME": "main-web-%DATE%.log",
        "LOGGING_MAIN_SYMLINK_NAME": "main-web.log",
        "ENV": "dev",
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH": "/home/myapp-user/.myapp-server-env",
        "SERVER_BASE_URL": "http://localhost:3000"
      }
    }]
  }
```

The location portion of our nginx config:

```
   location /api {
        root /var/www/sites/myapp.mydomain.com-api;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:300;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PM2 has built-in load balancing, so in case if app runs in cluster mode, it will allow using same port on all of the instances. Nginx will resolve instances on each request in Round-robin fashion

This behaviour is also documented in Node.js cluster mode docs
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works